# How to display coordinates from graphite in grafana worldmap panel

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have a graphite timeseries database with the following metrics for a moving object:

- object.latitude
- object.longitude
- object.status

I would like to plot the object status on in a grafana worldmap panel, but I am not able to link the graphite query in grafana to the worldmap-panel fields for latitude and longitude.

From what I understand the worldmap-panel expects a table formatted result, but how to generate this table by querying graphite?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a name and a metric for each point on the worldmap panel:
[image: resulting map]

I never used graphite, but on PostgreSQL you can do something like this:

```
select avg(latitude) || ', ' || avg(longitude) AS name,
  avg(latitude) as lat,
  avg(longitude) as lon,
  status as metric
from object
where $__timeFilter(timestamp_ms)
and pos != '(0, 0)'
```

make sure you set the Map Data options to Table and adjust the field mapping on the side panel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, indeed with postgresql this works. Unfortunately I am not able to figure out the query for graphite to achieve something similar, even when using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring more plugins I found a way to display lat lon metrics on a map with this plugin:
https://github.com/eh-steve/alexandra-trackmap-panel
branch: multiple-track-support